# Which token is supposed to be used in IdentityServer after external signin?

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, openid

When a user signs into my app using an external provider, does he then use the token from that provider to call the app's API or must the app generate its own token?

Comment: If the external login is implemented in Identity Server, after Identity Server receives the id token/access token from the external provider, it will decode the token and obtain the user’s statement, log in the user, then create the identity server’s own token, and finally return to Your client application. Identity Server will not process tokens from external providers, you can read this article:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/additional-claims?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The token that IdentityServer receives from the external provider is not passed down to the client, instead IdentityServer will issue its own tokens based on the received data in the external token.

The client and API's using IdentityServer only trusts token issued by it, not by the external service. In this way you can have one or many services that IdentityServer trusts, but your client/API only trusts IndentityServer.

Hope that makes things a bit clearer

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I wanted to know